# How to execute a windows program from Adobe Air?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

can you please tell me how can i run a program from Adobe air application like for some event i want to run utorrent or word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672021/adobe-air-to-execute-program)