# Access command line in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I've searched on stackoverflow, but didn't find anything, and looked through the as3 documentation with the same result.
I want to do something like C's `system();` or PHP's `shell_exec(")`.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adobe AIR to execute program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672021/adobe-air-to-execute-program)

Comment: That's possible only in AIR application. It's restricted to call any system process from browser applications.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine that, but couldn't you call a system process at the server?

Comment: @Laurent Okay, I didn't recognize Adobe AIR as `as3`... But I want to keep it as3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flash is client-side so you cannot call an executable on the server directly.

You could however create a PHP File on the server that would run your executable. Then you can launch this script from Flash using URLLoader:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://example.com/somescript.php');
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

Comment: Flash is client-side this is true only in web, AS3 run in Desktop AIR